# App Crashing : Bugsense giving this output as error: libsystem_c.dylib at :749

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash

App Crashing : Bugsense giving this output as error: libsystem_c.dylib at :749

Below is the Crash Log:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

749 is not the line number, but the memory offset of the last code executed in the libsystem_c.dylib framework.

But this doesn't help you and is not the cause of the crash anyway! A crash is mostly not caused by the upmost line, and sometimes also not but the thread that crashed.

You need to symbolicate the crash report and then especially take a look at your code that is invoked in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Kemi but can you tell me how to symbolicate the crash report?

Comment: There is a symbolicate link on that page, maybe that works for you. Otherwise you need to download the crash report and try to symbolicate locally. There are multiple discussions on StackOverflow on how to do that.